# How Monero transactions related with mixins

Tags: monerod, mymonero, monero-research-lab

Can anyone explain me is there a relationship between transaction outputs with the number of mixins using in the transaction? I meant If someone sends 12XMR to someone else with 5-mixins how many outputs could be there? Any idea of it? For above Tx number of inputs is 6? Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

"Mixins," known more commonly as "decoys," impact the input side of the transaction. They do not have anything to do with the number of outputs.

Each input has the number of decoys included in the ring signature. If multiple inputs are used, then there will be multiple ring signatures, each with their own set of decoys.

Each transaction has a minimum of two outputs, even if there is no change.

If I send 12 XMR in a single input to a single person with 5 decoys (6 ringsize), then the transaction will have 6 total possible inputs and two outputs.

If I send 12 XMR in two inputs (eg: 10 XMR and 2 XMR) to a single person with 5 decoys (6 ringsize), then the transaction will have 12 possible inputs (6 ringsize x 2 spent inputs) and two outputs.

Comment: FWIW, I've rarely seen them called "decoys". They're usually "(fake) ring members" or "fake outputs".